VBA - UserForm - If Option = False then delete rows where column = ''
I have created a user form where I want users to select the items they would like to keep in their project plan and remove the items that are not checked.
Currently this is my code but it obviously doesn't evaluate at one time so the rows are off. Is there a way to combine all these If statements to evaluate and delete rows at the same time? OR how can I have it remove the rows where critera matches "X"
Current Code Ex:
'Comp Prod Page'
    If FormDesign_CheckBox.Value = False Then
    Set Formdes_rng = Union(Range("a93:n296"), Range("a415:n416"))
    If Not Formdes_rng Is Nothing Then Formdes_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If Fax_CheckBox.Value = False Then
    Set Fax_rng = Union(Range("a97:n99"), Range("a235:n236"), Range("a417:n418"))
    If Not Fax_rng Is Nothing Then Fax_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    ElseIf PortalDesign_CheckBox.Value = False Then
    Set PortalDesign_rng = Union(Range("a100:n103"), Range("a237:n238"), Range("a419:n420"))
    If Not PortalDesign_rng Is Nothing Then PortalDesign_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If SigCapt_CheckBox.Value = False Then
    Set SigCapt_rng = Range("a104:n107")
    If Not SigCapt_rng Is Nothing Then SigCapt_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

I'd like to change the statement to look at criteria in column O
Ex:
If Fax_CheckBox.Value = False Then
    Set Fax_rng = Union(Range("a97:n99"), Range("a235:n236"), Range("a417:n418"))
    If Not Fax_rng Is Nothing Then Fax_rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If


Should ElseIf PortalDesign_CheckBox.Value = False Then be If PortalDesign_CheckBox.Value = False Then?

Why are you hard-coding the cell references?

Sorry that was a typo from me playing around. Elseif shouldn't be there. I tried that but because there could be multiple boxes checked, didn't same way I did the first set of checkboxes. Hardcoding because I am a beginner. I know it shouldn't be that way. That's why I want to change it instead of hardcoding a range to delete rows where column 0 = "xyz criteria"
